# Link to ID jumps back to jumbotron

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

---

It works on my webserver correctly...
Problem occurs only in my development environment with brackets

---

I have a Link to the first section in the jumbotron. When I click it, it jumps to the section and immediately back to the jumbotron. Now I can't even scroll down to the section. It seems it is stuck to the jumbotron.

```
<a href="#texting" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-round btn-lg mt-2"><small><span class="icon-arrow-down-circle pr-2"></span></small>blub</a>
```

I tried it with another ID or to another section but always the same problem. The "same" link in the navigation works correctly and jumps to the section #texting.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <!-- Wichtige Meta Daten -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Rollywood</title>

    <!-- CSS
  ============================================================================================= -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600|Spectral:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <!-- Start Navigation -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top hero-bg">
            <div class="container mx-auto nav-line">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#impressionen" class="nav-link">Impressionen</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#partner" class="nav-link">Partner</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- navbar-nav -->
                </div>
                <!-- navbar-collapse -->

                <!-- container -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Ende Navigation -->


    <!-- Header -->
    <section id="home" class="hero-bg jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto">
                <div class="col">
                <hr class="mb-5" style="background: white;">
                <br>
                <img class="img-logo mt-5 pt5 mx-auto img-fluid d-block img-responsive" src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="Rollywood-Logo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto">
                <div class="col">
                <br>
                <a href="#texting" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-round btn-lg mt-2"><small><span class="icon-arrow-down-circle pr-2"></span></small>blub</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- col -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </section>
    </header>
    <!-- Header -->


    <!-- Hero
  ============================================================================================= -->




    <!-- Section
    ============================================================================================= -->



    <section id="texting" class="d-relative pt-5">
        <div class="container section-line">
            <div class="row align-items-start justify-content-center mb-5">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                    <img class="align-self-start img-fluid mt-5 d-block mx-auto img-responsive" src="resources/img/writing_03.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-5">
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <h2 class="section-title mb-2 text-uppercase ">Texting</h2>
                            <img class="mb-5 mx-auto img-fluid d-block img-responsive" src="resources/img/linie.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group ul-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Ihnen die Worte fehlen.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Ihnen die entscheidenden Worte fehlen.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn bestehende Texte nicht begeistern.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn es um Emotionen geht.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Sie Emotionen wecken wollen.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Sie Ihre bevorstehende Ansprache sprachlos macht.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Ihre Worte tatenlos bleiben.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Sie mit Worten führen wollen.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Sie einen Grund zum Feiern haben.</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><span class="icon-pencil mr-3"></span>Wenn Tränen fliessen und Worte helfen können.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <h4 class="mt-5 section-title2">Dann ist ROLLYWOOD für Sie da</h4>
                        <h5 class="mb-5 section-title2">weil Worte Menschen bewegen.</h5>
                        <p class="mb-5">
                            Das ausgewogene Wort im richtigen Moment kann Berge versetzen und Ihre Mitmenschen begeistern. Ob das Ihre Leser oder Ihre Zuhörer sind, Ihr Business- oder Ihr Familienumfeld ist, ob Sie was zum Feiern oder zum besinnlichen Nachdenken haben - das macht für uns hinsichtlich Anspruch und Notwendigkeit keinen Unterschied.
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <blockquote>
                                <p class="mb-5">
                                    „Wir glauben an die Kraft des subtil gewählten Wortes. An die Wirkung und die Magie, die es in uns Menschen auslöst. Und uns bewegt.“
                                </p>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            mehr Info: <a href="mailto:words@rolimeyer.ch" target="_top">E-Mail</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- Scripts
  ============================================================================================= -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be reproducible with your code. Most likely there is something else going on in the custom JS and/or CSS.

Comment: It seems to be a problem only in my development environment... I uploaded exactly the hole folder to my webserver and than it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on my webserver correctly... Problem occurs only in my development environment with brackets

Comment: I cannot confirm any anomalies in Brackets 1.11 build 1.11.0-17524 (which isn't the latest version).

Comment: I have Release 1.12 Build 1.12.0-17621